# Logical operators in C# used as words 'is' and 'and'

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

In the code base of the project that I'm working on I saw a syntax for equality checks and for a range check between enums like that:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
  Monday,
  Tuesday,
  Wednesday,
  Thursday,
  Friday,
  Saturday,
  Sunday,
}

public static partial class Extensions
{
  public static bool IsWeekDay(this DaysOfWeek value) => value is <= DaysOfWeek.Friday and >= DaysOfWeek.Monday;
}

var isWeekDay = DaysOfWeek.Monday.IsWeekDay();
Console.WriteLine(isWeekDay);
// True
```

I mean the syntax is self explanatory but I didn't know that this kind of syntax exists in C# and when I tried to search in google I didn't found any information or any example. I even tried asking the free version of chatGPT and his answer was that probably there is some extensions installed for this behavior to work without any compile or run time errors. So if any of you had used this syntax and know how it is installed as extension or if its from the new versions of C# I will be happy to learn something new.

Comment: "[pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns)" is the word(s) you lacked to find anything useful.

Comment: _"I even tried asking the free version of chatGPT"_ - I'd actually _not_ recommend that. Once more I have heard now of it leading beginners in a completely wrong direction.

Comment: That was quite fast, thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) and if I remember correctly was introduced in C# 7 ([spec for C# 7 feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/patterns)) and was gradually improved in the following releases with addition of different patterns (like [List patterns in C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/list-patterns) or [Extended property patterns in C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/extended-property-patterns)).

Comment: Thank you, I'm really grateful for that information!

Comment: @SimeonYordanov was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left)